# I can't figure out why I'm not able to select an attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have some input tags like this:

```
<input data-role="none" id="TaskActionList.SpaceId" type="hidden" value="@Model.CombinedAvailableSpaces.Single().SpaceId" name="" data-inputname="TaskActionList" data-propertyname="SpaceId" data-singlespace="true"/>
```

(I have about 3 of the exact same input tag on my page)

I want to get the last attribute value: 'true' from the very last attribute on my input tag. I've tried this jquery but I keep getting a value of undefined:

```
$('input').attr('data-singlespace')
```

I should get back the word 'true' but instead I get undefined. Why could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns the specified attribute from the first element in the jQuery object. In your case the jQuery object `$('input')` selects every input element on the page, so you're trying to get that attribute from the first input where (presumably) the attribute isn't defined.

Change your selector to be sure to get the correct element.

Comment: that did the trick. I had a whole bunch of other input tags also on my page. I just added a class to the one I wanted and got it. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is a better idea to use `.data()` method to access custom attributes

```
$('input').data('singlespace')
```

The problem might also be because of multiple inputs.

Put the code inside `$.each`

```
$('input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('singlespace'));
});
```

Or use `eq` to target a specific input based on the index as the selector is too specific.

```
$('input').eq(1).data('singlespace') ;
// Gets the 2nd input
```

Comment: yes, that's what I'm doing. I just didn't show the encasing. thanks

Comment: using data didn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: Why is `.data()` "better"? It tries to do automatic type conversion on the attribute value, which admittedly in this case might be useful if it returns a boolean `true` rather than the string `"true"`, but in other cases the conversion can be a problem.

Comment: @nnnnnn.. Type conversion is a problem when retrieving the attribute using the method. But I thought it would be more apt in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

you could also try this:

```
$('input[data-singlespace]').data('singlespace');
```